# Convert Canny edge detection into np.array

Tags: python, arrays, edge-detection

I have written a function where I want to detect the edges of an image using the Canny algorithm. I then want to extract the 2d array of this image, and then flatten it into a 1d array.

```
def canny_detection(image):

    # Convert to grayscale and convert the image to float
    RGB = img_as_float(color.rgb2gray(image))

    # Apply Canny edge detection algorithm
    edge_canny = feature.canny(RGB, 3).astype(int)

    #Get output array
    canny_arr = np.array(edge_canny)

    # Flatten output array
    canny_flat = canny_arr.flatten()

    return canny_flat
```

However, when I call the function with an example image, the output is just a huge array of 0s. I'm sure that's not right. I've tested the canny algorithm on the image, and the resulting image is correct. But the problem is when I want to get the vector of the image.

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect problem might be in that line:

```
edge_canny = feature.canny(RGB, 3).astype(int)
```

please replace it with

```
edge_canny = feature.canny(RGB, 3)
print(edge_canny)
edge_canny = edge_canny.astype(int)
print(edge_canny)
```

and check what it prints, if first is some nonzero float values `<1.0` and second is `0`s, that probably means that `feature.canny` produces values from `0.0` to `1.0` and then you lose it converting to `int`.
EDIT: Fixed my code.

Comment: Ok, i tried that and now it's giving me the following error:

`ValueError    Traceback (most recent call last)`
`<ipython-input-71-5c0465ddfe4d> in <module>()`
`----> 1 canny_detection(image1)`

`<ipython-input-70-913c49fa1908> in canny_detection(image)8`     # Apply Canny edge detection algorithm`
      `9     edge_canny = feature.canny(RGB, 3)`
`---> 10     print(max(edge_canny))`
     `11     edge_canny = edge_canny.astype(int)`
     `12     print(max(edge_canny))`

`ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

Comment: Sorry, I can't get it format better in the comment. I tried the np.any but it still didn't work

Comment: No, the first print gives me a matrix of all `False` and the second one a matrix of all `0`......

Comment: Ok, now with the edit I get the following:

`True` and `1`

Comment: Wait is `feature.canny(RGB, 3)`supposed to produce array of `bool`s?

Comment: According to [http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.feature.html#skimage.feature.canny] yeah, that's not the problem I think..But I shouldn't be getting an array of all `0`s

Comment: Please check if `canny_flat` is consisting solely of `0`s, by adding `print(np.count_nonzero(canny_flat))` before `return`. If it is `>0` then it contains also other values.

Comment: Output: `22348` So the matrix is just so large that the non-zero values can't be seen

Comment: Unfortunately not...Later in the code I call the function inside a for loop because I want it to iterate over some images in a file. But when I do I get the error `TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable` referring to `canny_det = canny_detection(image)` which is inside the for loop...